# 2D Array Not Translating to D3 Map Coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, multidimensional-array

The 2D array I created is not accepted by D3.js as coordinates (The *map example* I'm using is at http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/6522279.)

#### Here are the facts:

1.) The JSON **input** I am supplied with is a string of latitude and longitude (e.g. `"37.3879 -134.96376"`).

2.) The **output** required is a 2D array that must be in this form `[[lat,long],[lat,long],...]`.

3.) `console.log(typeof(lat));` returns that the lat and long values are indeed numbers (not strings)

4.) `console.log("Coordinates: " + JSON.stringify(points));` returns *`[[37.3879,-134.96376],[13.5,-45],...]`* - which appears to be in the correct form, yet no points are displayed on the map

5.) If I hardcode the values in the array the points are displayed.

```
var points = [];
//var dotSpot = [[1.4440, 32.442], [12.222, 4.893]];

window.onload = function () {
    getJSON();
} 

function getJSON(supplierID) {
    //retrieves JSON perfectly
    //calls make() with Supplier data
}

function make(jdata) {

    for (var i = 0; i < jdata.length; i++) {
        //Splits string by space
        var temp = jdata[i].latLong.split(/[ ,]+/)
        //Converts lat and long strings to floats
        var lat = parseFloat(temp[0]);
        var long = parseFloat(temp[1]);
        console.log(typeof(lat)); 

        //Add "curr" coordinates array to "points" array
        var curr = new Array(lat, long);
        points.push(curr);

    }

    console.log("Coordinates: " + JSON.stringify(points)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified your coordinates to be `[latitude, longitude]`. However, unlike many other applications D3 uses coordinates with longitude as the first value followed by latitude. From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#_projection):

> The point must be specified as a two-element array [*longitude*, *latitude*] in degrees.

Changing you data accordingly should yield the desired rendering:

```
var curr = new Array(long, lat);   // instead of new Array(lat, long)
points.push(curr);
```